# How to put an array stored in properties file into a JSP variable

Tags: jsp, jstl, properties-file

How to put an array formed by a value stored on properties file (comma separated) to a variable in a JSP file without using Java instructions but using EL expression or JSTL?

In the properties file:

```
vals.value=element1, element2, element3
```

What do I need to put in the JSP file to put element1, element2, element3 as an array?

Comment: If you don't want to do any scripting in your JSP, then create a Servlet to the job. You could do the work in the init method of a  Servlet that you configured to load-on-startup. That way you could put it into application-scope and it be there when you want to access it in your JSP.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a custom tag or a "tag  file" .

Answer (score 2):

you can load propert file using following method, then store value as per your way.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%> 
<fmt:bundle basename="property file name"/>
<fmt:message key="error.more" />
```